# Why am I getting such error message in Installing Package?

Tags: c++, c, linux, fft, fftw

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04.
I am looking to install [This Package](https://github.com/xdsopl/spectrum).
I have already installed packages:
'fftw2', 'fftw-dev', 'fftw-doc', 'fftw-3.3.4'

However, when I try to `root@ubuntu:~/spectrum-master# make`:

```
cc -lm -lasound -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL -lfftw3f -lm spectrum.o mmap_file.o pcm.o wav.o alsa.o window.o stft.o cqt.o trans.o -o spectrum
spectrum.o: In function handle_events': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:27: undefined reference toSDL_PollEvent'
spectrum.o: In function srgb': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:78: undefined reference to__powf_finite'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:76: undefined reference to __powf_finite' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:77: undefined reference to__powf_finite'
spectrum.o: In function main': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:126: undefined reference toSDL_Init'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:127: undefined reference to SDL_SetVideoMode' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:143: undefined reference toSDL_WM_SetCaption'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:144: undefined reference to SDL_EnableKeyRepeat' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:199: undefined reference to__log10f_finite'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:157: undefined reference to SDL_Flip' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/spectrum.c:158: undefined reference toSDL_Delay'
alsa.o: In function write_alsa': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:71: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_writei'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:72: undefined reference to snd_pcm_prepare' alsa.o: In functionread_alsa':
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:54: undefined reference to snd_pcm_readi' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:55: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_prepare'
alsa.o: In function close_alsa': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:26: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_drain'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:27: undefined reference to snd_pcm_close' alsa.o: In functionopen_alsa_read':
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:92: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:92: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:94: undefined reference to snd_pcm_open' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:100: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_any'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:107: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:114: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:121: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:130: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_min'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:109: undefined reference to snd_pcm_close' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:137: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:144: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:151: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels'
alsa.o: In function open_alsa_write': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:177: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:177: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:179: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_open'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:185: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_any' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:192: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:199: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:206: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:213: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:218: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels_near'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:223: undefined reference to snd_pcm_hw_params' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/alsa.c:194: undefined reference tosnd_pcm_close'
window.o: In function sinc': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/window.c:14: undefined reference tosinf'
window.o: In function hann': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/window.c:24: undefined reference tocosf'
window.o: In function hamming': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/window.c:29: undefined reference tocosf'
window.o: In function sinc': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/window.c:14: undefined reference tosinf'
window.o: In function gauss': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/window.c:38: undefined reference to__expf_finite'
stft.o: In function free_stft': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/stft.c:44: undefined reference tofftwf_destroy_plan'
stft.o: In function get_stft': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/stft.c:38: undefined reference tocabsf'
stft.o: In function create_stft': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/stft.c:66: undefined reference tofftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d'
stft.o: In function slide_stft': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/stft.c:31: undefined reference tofftwf_execute'
cqt.o: In function get_cqt': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:33: undefined reference tocabsf'
cqt.o: In function free_cqt': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:47: undefined reference tofftwf_destroy_plan'
cqt.o: In function create_cqt': /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:65: undefined reference to__logf_finite'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:65: undefined reference to __expf_finite' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:66: undefined reference to__log2_finite'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:87: undefined reference to fftwf_plan_dft_1d' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:98: undefined reference tocexpf'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:103: undefined reference to fftwf_execute' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:57: undefined reference tocabsf'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:57: undefined reference to cabsf' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:115: undefined reference tocabsf'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:117: undefined reference to cabsf' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:117: undefined reference tocabsf'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:57: undefined reference to __powf_finite' /home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:139: undefined reference tofftwf_destroy_plan'
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:146: undefined reference to fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d' cqt.o: In functionslide_cqt':
/home/userKum/spectrum-master/cqt.c:30: undefined reference to `fftwf_execute'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [spectrum] Error 1
```

I have no idea what these undefined reference is all about...... It looks it is missing a linkage to `'-lasound'` during compilation. What should I do so that I can solve this issue?

---

---

As requested by some of the viewer, the MakeFile is as follows:

```
CFLAGS = -g -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -W -Wall -O3 -std=c99 -fno-math-errno -ffinite-math-only -fno-rounding-math -fno-signaling-nans -fno-trapping-math -fcx-limited-range -fsingle-precision-constant $(shell sdl-config --cflags) $(shell pkg-config fftw3f --cflags)
LDFLAGS = -lm -lasound $(shell sdl-config --libs) $(shell pkg-config fftw3f --libs)

all: spectrum

clean:
    rm -f spectrum *.o

spectrum: spectrum.o mmap_file.o pcm.o wav.o alsa.o window.o stft.o cqt.o trans.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Another classic case of "libraries need to come after the objects":

Your libraries, defined by

```
LDFLAGS = -lm -lasound $(shell sdl-config --libs) $(shell pkg-config fftw3f --libs)
```

Given that (according to here) the rule for linking is:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

I would expect that

```
LDLIBS = -lm -lasound $(shell sdl-config --libs) $(shell pkg-config fftw3f --libs)
```

would do the trick, although I prefer to actually write my own linker line, as inevitably I end up wanting to know exactly what is linked...

(Unix linkers are rather simplistic in their dealing with libraries, so if you list `-lsomething x.o`  to the linker, the linker will not take anything from -lsomething, and complaim that `somethingFunc1`(which can be found in `libsomething.a`) is missing because it wasn't found AFTER `x.o`.